# Store directory path in variable?

Tags: ksh

I want to store a path like `c:\abhor\test` in a variable but it is treated as `\a`,`\t`. I don't want to use `c:\\abhor\\test`. Please provide some solution to this problem?

Comment: Use single quotes. `var='c:\abhor\test'`

Comment: Its not wrking...saying invalid path

Comment: What platform are you on?  Which version/distribution of ksh are you using? Ksh93 provides UNIX to host-name file mapping on non-UNIX machines with `typeset -H pathname`.  This automatically happens for ksh93 on windows (uwin or cygwin) for `PATH`, and any variable names mentioned in `DOSPATHVARS`

Comment: Just use forward slashes (`/`). They should work under Cygwin, surely?